# How to process shipping charges and VAT using Google Checkout?

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

I need to implement google checkout using asp.net c#, I was able to get items in my shopping cart populated in google checkout, but was unable to proceed with shipping charges and VAT and what to do after that, i.e., track orders and redirecting to my site so I could add customer's orders. kindly provide me with complete implementation sample if possible i will be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Google provides sample code, which should effectively provide an integration sample:

[.Net Sample Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-dotnet-sample-code/)

and

[Google Checkout XML API Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html)

Answer (score 0):

For .NET integration issues I also recommend the Checkout Developer forums:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/checkout-merchants/label?lid=254e6cb63ecd682f&hl=en